# why 1 is the result produced by expression

Tags: c

Can someone explain why this expression produces 1 as result?

```
i = 1 && 2 + 3 | 4;
```

What is exactly the order of the operations here?

Comment: learn precedenct and c, ask questions later

Comment: Here's a handy link: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

Comment: [Clicky](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

Comment: See the order of operations here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: `i = (1 && (2 + (3 | 4))) //will result in 1 or 0`,nothing tricky in that,huh.

Comment: Hey, you guys gave it for C++. Almost the same, but not quite ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the operator precedence, `+` has highest precedence so is evaluated first, then `|` (bitwise or), then `&&` (logical and):

```
i = 1 && ((2 + 3) | 4)
```

Evaluating this out:

```
i = 1 && (5 | 4)
```

`|` is bitwise or, which returns a value which has a bit set in every location that either of its operands have a bit set. 5 is `101` in binary, 4 is `100`, so the bitwise or is `101`, or 5:

```
i = 1 && 5
```

Now `&&` is logical and, which returns 1 if both of the values are true values. Anything besides 0 is a true value, so it returns 1.

Answer (score 9):

```
i = (1 && ((2 + 3) | 4)))
```

Boolean expression in C always evaluates to 0 or 1. Anything that's not 0 is considered true.

> - 1 != 0
> - 2 + 3 == 5
> - 5 | 4 == 5 (| is the bitwise or operator)
> - 5 != 0
> - 1 && 5 == 1

Comment: I believe it's rather: `i = (1 && ((2 + 3) | 4))`

Comment: Bitwise operators are lower precedence then you might think (now fixed in this answer).

Comment: "What is exactly the order of the operations here?" is this not completely unanswerable?  The test if `1 != 0` in `1 && ...` could occur before _or_ after the evaluation of `((2 + 3) | 4)) != 0`.  The order of these 2 operations is left to the compiler to decide. This is why `i++ && --i` is UB.

Answer (score 1):

Look up the C Precedence Table when you are not sure.

[Operators in C and C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence)